# SQL Backup not working with PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-get-contents

I am using the script found at this [blog post](http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php).

What I am trying to do is output the SQL Code onto the screen and then using file_get_contents from my local web server to get the SQL Query and `mysql_query` it to my local database.

The problem is when I do this it gives me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO...

If I copy and paste the SQL Code from the screen it's executed perfectly fine.

I know this is quite a weird request but if someone could help me find the problem it'll be great.

Comment: Unfortunately not as it contains client information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i used this

```
    $file = file_get_contents("db-backup-1316832550-6f1ed002ab5595859014ebf0951522d9.sql");
foreach(explode(';', $file) as $value => $key)
{
if($key == ''){continue;}

echo $key;
mysql_query($key) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

of course the file is example one

there's seems to be a problem with the delimiter = ";"